# Deserializing an array of different object types

Tags: c#, json.net

Using the [Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) library, I'm having trouble deserializing some json returned as an array. The json is an array containing some paging information as an object and array of country objects. Here's a sample of the returned json:

```
[
    {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 6,
        "per_page": "50",
        "total": 262
    },
    [
        {
            "id": "ABW",
            "iso2Code": "AW",
            "name": "Aruba",
            "region": {
                "id": "LCN",
                "value": "Latin America & Caribbean (all income levels)"
            },
            "adminregion": {
                "id": "",
                "value": ""
            },
            "incomeLevel": {
                "id": "NOC",
                "value": "High income: nonOECD"
            },
            "lendingType": {
                "id": "LNX",
                "value": "Not classified"
            },
            "capitalCity": "Oranjestad",
            "longitude": "-70.0167",
            "latitude": "12.5167"
        }
    ]
]
```

I am attempting to deserialize to the following types:

```cs
class CountriesQueryResults
{
    public PagingInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
    public List<CountryInfo> Countries { get; set; }
}

class PagingInfo
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("per_page")]  
    public int ResultsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

class CountryInfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Iso2Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string CapitalCity { get; set; }
    public CompactIdentifier Region { get; set; }
    public CompactIdentifier AdminRegion { get; set; }
    public CompactIdentifier IncomeLevel { get; set; }
    public CompactIdentifier LendingType { get; set; }  
}

class CompactIdentifier
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling DeserializeObject as so:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountriesQueryResults>>(response);
```

I am getting the following error:

`Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type   'CountriesQueryResults' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`

I have been trying to get the answer from [the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm) but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18192564/95573

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your json is like this `[ {....} , [{....}] ]`, You can only deserialize it to an object array(Where first item is an object and second, another array).

This simplest way I think to convert it to a c# object is:

```
var jArr = JArray.Parse(jsonstr);
var pageInfo = jArr[0].ToObject<PagingInfo>();
var countryInfos = jArr[1].ToObject<List<CountryInfo>>();
```

Class definitions would be:

```
public class PagingInfo
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("per_page")]
    public int ResultsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class AdminRegion
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class IncomeLevel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class LendingType
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class CountryInfo
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string iso2Code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Region region { get; set; }
    public AdminRegion adminregion { get; set; }
    public IncomeLevel incomeLevel { get; set; }
    public LendingType lendingType { get; set; }
    public string capitalCity { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
}
```

PS: You can change the property names' first char to Uppercase if you want. I used http://json2csharp.com/ to automatically generate those classes.