# How to filter only array from JSON

Tags: c#, json

My JSON string is as follows,

```
{  
   "Data":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "Name":"Sachin"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "Name":"Rahul"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "Name":"Sovrav"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I want to filter only array from that JSON string and store them in another variable the result should be like this

```
[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "Name":"Sachin"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "Name":"Rahul"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "Name":"Sovrav"
      }
   ]
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Newtonsoft.JSon](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) - [Nuget Package Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)?

Following Newtonsoft you could do this:

Create a **model** to Deserialize your JSON

```
public class DataJson {
    List<PersonJson> Data { get; set; }
}

public class PersonJson {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialize** your Json object easily:
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

For a similar question you could look here: [Deserializing JSON Object Array with Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192357/deserializing-json-object-array-with-json-net)

Some keywords for searching more information would be: Deserialize, Json, C#

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and deserialize object and serialize only list.

```
public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
} 

static void Main()
{
    string json = "{   \"Data\":[ { \"id\":\"1\", \"Name\":\"Sachin\" }, { \"id\":\"2\", \"Name\":\"Rahul\" }, { \"id\":\"3\", \"Name\":\"Sovrav\" } ] }";

    RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro.Data);
}
```

And `newJson` contains:

> [{"id":"1","Name":"Sachin"},{"id":"2","Name":"Rahul"},{"id":"3","Name":"Sovrav"}]