# .net C# JArray how to get data out of it?

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to consume an API service that will give me some data back in JSON that will then be used in a winForm Project.

I Used the following backend code:

```
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString (sURL);
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        dynamic array = JArray.Parse(json);
```

reulting in the following data:

```
    {
        {"AppId": 1, 
        "applications": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tencent\\WeChat\\WeChat.exe", 
        "recordId": 1,            
        "userId": 1}
    }
```

So I expected I could use array["applications"] to get my data but it turned out i was wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This JSON is not valid !

Comment: you have to deserialize it to a object and then use it..Create a class with Appid and applications and deserialise the results array to its class..this can be helpful to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192357/deserializing-json-object-array-with-json-net

Comment: Deserialization to object is not mandatory, give proper json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming if this was your json:

```
[
{"AppId": 1, 
"applications": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tencent\\WeChat\\WeChat.exe", 
"recordId": 1,            
"userId": 1}
]
```

you can use  `JArray a= JArray.Parse(json);` and loop through.

Answer (score 2):

After using James his answer I was able to do the following to solve my problem. both in a loop as well as a single variable.

```
        var resulti = "";
        JArray app = JArray.Parse(json);

        // single var
        var tester = app[0]["applications"];

        // loop
        foreach (var item in app)
        {
            resulti += item["applications"];
        }
```