# Load Json from URL C#

Tags: c#, json

I need to load JSON from a URL, and not know why (in this format).

In this ask, all solved: [Dynamically load Json from URL on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890875/dynamically-load-json-from-url-on-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment86797743_49890875)

But at this time, i need parse this JSON:

```
{"Markets":[{"Label":"CHEESE/BTC","Name":"Cheese","Price":0.00000012,"Volume_24h":0.26702542,"Timestamp":1524662820}]}
```

The format of JSON is diferent. Tryed like this, but not work:

```
json = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.worldcoinindex.com/apiservice/ticker?key=0b6dmpsEyLlR7meh1QfALwEGE6dC3J&label=cheesebtc&fiat=btc");

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

 if (obj.success == "true")
 {
     foreach (var result in obj.result)
     {
         if (result.Name == "Price")
             textbox1.text = result.value.ToString();
     }
 }
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, not return value. Put a error on test if obj.sucess.

Comment: You should not post code containing sensitive information, like an API key

Comment: If you inspect it in Visual Studio, are there any error messages in the object? And thanks for the key :P

Comment: No error in Visual Studio (or i dont know correct inspect).

Comment: About the key, its not really private, not problem to share.

Comment: @OdacirCristofolini Considering that the API is not the problem, posting the API link complete with secret key is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Make a model as below. And explicitly convert dynamic obj to that class.

```
public class Markets
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Volume_24h { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
}


dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Markets>(json);
```

Or

```
Markets obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Markets>(json);
```