# JSON to C# class issue

Tags: c#, json

I'm new to JSON and I'm trying to convert JSON data to C# class, but I always get errors when converting to C# entity class. Can someone tell me how to properly convert the following JSON data to C# class? Thank you very much! orz

```
[
    {
        "place_id":121943890,
        "licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
        "osm_type":"way",
        "osm_id":195289214,
        "boundingbox":["28.0650511","28.0769594","112.9936342","113.0111091"],
        "lat":"28.07081905",
        "lon":"113.002623874342",
        "display_name":"Changsha",
        "class":"amenity",
        "type":"university",
        "importance":0.11100000000000002,
        "icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/education_university.p.20.png",
        "geojson":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
                [
                    [112.9936342,28.0740059],
                    [112.9957532,28.0699078],
                    [112.9968442,28.0691153],
                    [112.9970274,28.0689822],
                    [113.0003451,28.0669209],
                    [113.0012613,28.0650511],
                    [113.0111091,28.0676428],
                    [113.0096377,28.0717303],
                    [113.0084561,28.0746411],
                    [113.0074304,28.0769594],
                    [113.0015116,28.0756923],
                    [113.0011744,28.0756201],
                    [112.9936342,28.0740059]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: You should try out [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/)

Comment: How did you convert it?

Comment: There’s multiple ways to handle it as a class. If you tried something and got errors, include the code and the errors. Otherwise we can’t say anything about what is the problem.

Comment: Actualy, this is a correct [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192357/deserializing-json-object-array-with-json-net) to set it as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
public class Geojson
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int place_id { get; set; }
    public string licence { get; set; }
    public string osm_type { get; set; }
    public int osm_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> boundingbox { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string @class { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public double importance { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public Geojson geojson { get; set; }
}
```

I used this tool to do it 
http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I just tried it, but the following error is still reported

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:“Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'OSMDataGet.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"...
Path '', line 1, position 1.”

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) for this. Just paste your JSON in and it will produce c# equivalent data structures along with some sample code to serialize and deserialize using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

You can change the class names and property names after the fact, but you should not change the JsonProperty attributes.

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var welcome = Welcome.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("place_id")]
        public long PlaceId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("licence")]
        public string Licence { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("osm_type")]
        public string OsmType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("osm_id")]
        public long OsmId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("boundingbox")]
        public string[] Boundingbox { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lat")]
        public string Lat { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lon")]
        public string Lon { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("display_name")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("class")]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("importance")]
        public double Importance { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("icon")]
        public Uri Icon { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("geojson")]
        public Geojson Geojson { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Geojson
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
        public double[][][] Coordinates { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome[] FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome[]>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Welcome[] self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```